# Can two ElapsedEvent's, from the same System.Timers.Timer, run at the same time

Tags: c#, timer

In C#, when using the `System.Timers.Timer`, can the `ElapsedEvent` run if the previous one has not finished?
Imagine I have an event that takes longer to complete than I anticipated, and the timer's interval is up, before execution has finished. What happens then?

From what I could read on MSDN, `System.Timers` run on the threadpool, where as Windows Timers run single threaded. 
I am concerned that I will accidently run two (or more!) events at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Elapsed event will be fired again.
Reading carefully the MSDN Documentation that says:

`If the SynchronizingObject property is Nothing, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If the processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.`

Also using the Stop method doesn't ensure the end of Elapsed event because the Stop event could be queued in an different Thread respect the Interval event.

Again reading the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx) clarifies how to handle this situation

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can.

Two possible solutions:

- Specify a `SynchonizingObject` in your timer to prevent multiple threads from running at once. The problem here is that if your implementation takes longer than the timer timeout, then you calls will back up.
- Stop the timer at the start of your delegate, and restart it again at the end. This seems to be a more common pattern, but means that your events will not fire exactly on time unless you do some timing inside your callback. This may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely. Here's a short but complete program to demonstrate that:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += ElapsedHandler;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    static void ElapsedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Starting to sleep", id);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Exiting", id);
    }
}
```

How you deal with it is up to you. You could:

- Use the [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property to get more control
- Keep some sort of atomic or counter to say whether or not to *really* process the "tick"
- Take some sort of "abortive" action

... it really depends on your situation.